# Eclipse Add marker for linked resources

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, eclipse-rcp, marker

I know that markers can be added only for IResource(s), could they be added for linked resources ?
I've got the linked resource name from .project, using `org.eclipse.core.internal.Project.internalGetDescription()` and `getLinks()`.
But it seems that something is missing, Eclipse is complaining about the fact that the resource does not exist.
I'm creating the resource using `Workspace.newResource([PATH])`, where the PATH is an `IPath` built correctly using the linked resource name from .project and the rest of path towards the file name.

Maybe somebody has worked with this before ?

Comment: What markers do you want to bind to the linked resources?

Comment: I need to add markers for the Problems view (warning and errror): org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker .

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `Workspace.newResource([PATH])` directly, get the resource from the IProject or IWorkspaceRoot using its path and `#getFile()` or `#getFolder()`.  That it's a linked resource shouldn't matter if you're doing this right.  If you're still having problems, tell us exactly what its complaint is.